# Facebook ios sdk authorize opens two permissions request dialogs

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, authorize

Calling authorize from our game (using Facebook ios sdk 2.x or 3.1) results in two permissions dialogs in the Facebook App. Similar odd behaviour is demonstrated in the web browser if the Facebook App is not present on the device but I will refrain from describing that specific case.

During testing we found that...

**On iPhone**

Accepting the first permission dialog results in a blank dialog with a cancel button. Clicking on cancel will dismiss the dialog, briefly show a second (exact duplicate) permissions dialog, and then return the user to the app. If the user returns to the Facebook app, they will see the second permissions dialog still there.

**On iPad**

Accepting the first permission dialog often results in a blank dialog with a cancel button. Clicking on cancel (or if the cancel dialog doesn't show at all) will show a second (exact duplicate) permissions dialog. Clicking 'Allow' on this dialog will return the user to the app.

Here are some images to help illustrate the ipad case:

- First permission dialog shows: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s54/sh/3037a5b8-d55a-4bc2-ad11-a889202ca596/14f2e1241ee78c333c6cb2c8f978adfe
- User clicks 'Accept' and then Blank cancel dialog shows: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s54/sh/8ef40f24-7291-4592-9faa-9e2f322c0652/66ae6f4e43192510a7beeb9fb154bd04
- User clicks 'cancel' and then second permission dialog shows: (refer to first image... I hit my max 2 links already)
- User clicks 'Accept' and flow returns to the game (also not shown)

I've since tried out the same steps using a popular Facebook game - Diamond Dash. On iPad you will see a similar double permissions dialog (minus the blank cancel dialog). If you 'Allow' the first permission dialog, control will return to the game. If you then go back to the Facebook App, you'll see the second permission dialog hanging around.

Ultimately the user can get through the multiple dialogs and go on to play the game... but certainly the flow is messy.

So my questions are:

1) How can we get rid of the blank cancel dialog after accepting permissions and
2) How can we get rid of the double permission dialog (or at the very least ensure that on iPad, the first permission dialog will return the user to our app)

I've searched through other posts related to blank fb dialogs and so far everything points to session expiry (or re-asking for permissions after already being granted) so I believe this is a new bug report.

A few of the things I've tried on the Facebook site admin page:

- turned off enhanced auth dialog (no difference)
- turned off authenticated referrals (no difference)
- removed all permissions we ask for (no difference)
- using or not using an url scheme has no effect
- single and multiple bundle ids
- removing the iphone app id

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So after mucking with Facebook settings for awhile, it appears that setting the "Enhanced Auth Dialog" (in Advanced section) to true has fixed the problem with the blank cancel screen. The double permission dialog problem is still there, but since the second dialog is shown just before the user is flipped back to the game, it's not very disruptive.

Of note, new Facebook apps no longer have a setting for Enhanced Auth Dialog. I believe these newer apps force the setting to true.